# Expected behavior for using pointer beyond malloc allocated memory

Tags: c++, c

Just wondering, because I can't figure out a way to test this. Imagine the scenario whereby I have 10 bytes of memory

1. I malloc varA with 5 bytes
2. Assign a string with 7 characters (which use up 8 bytes)
3. I malloc varB with 5 bytes

Will the program run into an error? Or just end up with gibberish memory?

Does the behaviour varies from a c/c++ and a cuda program?

Comment: This question is basically "What will my program do if there's a bug in it?". The answer is basically "Probably not what you want or expect. That's why we avoid bugs."

Comment: **You don't do this!** This is not even a possibility. When you have a piece of paper and you write on it, when it's full you don't continue on the desk... or your mom will punish you. Same here!

Comment: **Leaks** are when you loose grip of pointers you allocated and did not free. That memory ends up in limbo. **Overflows** are when you overstep your boundaries writing. Both are deadly: first is a slower death, second not so much.

Comment: Haha, I like your comments. I pondered upon this because I was running someone else's source (on cuda) and it gave me serious headache because it worked while such a thing happened. But as you already know, when I continuously run the program... problems....

Comment: @springcold Go tell that guy that pointers are not just a starting point of writing. They have a `SIZE` and you don't overstep it. So it has both a beginning and an ending.

Comment: Changing Title to fit the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a memory leak, it's a *buffer overflow*. And those leads to *undefined behavior*, which will most likely give you weird problems (or even crashes) during run-time.

Unless you mean point 2 literally, like in

```
char *str = malloc(5);
str = "foobar";
```

Then you *do* have a memory leak, and *not* a buffer overflow.

Comment: I think that is safe to say that this is `undefined behaviour`, I don't know if it's equally true the fact that this will cause `buffer overflow`.

Comment: May I ask, will the behaviour likely be the same in Cuda as well?

Comment: @springcold The behavior is the same with any C-library.

Answer (score 0):

It is an undefined behavior to write beyond allocated memory.